# Мутабельность указателя в си

Tags: c, указатели, ссылки

Минимальный пример

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct map_s {
   struct map_s * next;
} map_t;

struct data {
  map_t * map;
};

void insert(map_t * map) {
  map_t * new = malloc(sizeof(map_t));
  new->next = map;
  fprintf (stderr,"\n%p", new);
  map = new;
}

int main() {
 struct data d;
 d.map = NULL;
 fprintf (stderr,"\n%p", d.map);
 insert(d.map);
 fprintf (stderr,"\n%p", d.map);
 return 0;
}
```

Я хочу чтоб `d.map` было равно `new` после выполнения функции.

Comment: Нужно передавать двойной указатель: `map_t **map`.

Comment: Так как аргументы передаются копией по значению, не имеет смысла вообще использовать аргументы. Используйте глобальную переменную. Можно даже заключённую в структуру `struct NameSpace{struct data d;} global;`

Comment: Как действуют например функция `realloc` : берёт аргументом указатель и возвращает новый. писать придётся `d.map = insert(d.map);`

Comment: Лучше сделать `map_t` (не указатель!) полем в `data`, а в `insert` как раз передавать указатель на этот объект, а не просто нулевой указатель. Также `new` лучше не использовать, так как этот идентификатор зарезервирован в C++.

Comment: Через присвоение сделал, но так не сделать `if (insert(d.map) ==0)` конструкцию

Comment: Вы ещё не знаете, что делают макросы : `# define Insert(P) ((P) = insert(P)) ` а дальше `if(Insert(d.map)==0)`

Comment: Двойной указатель самый правильный способ.

Comment: можно ответ с примером?

Comment: Сделайте `int insert(map_t **pmap)`.  Передавайте ей   адрес `map` и возвращайте признак ошибки. (совет, посмотрите на прототипы функций в /usr/include, подумайте, почему их так делали)

Answer (score 1):

Пример как пользоваться указателем на указатели и с добавлением обработки исключений как положено.

```
// gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c11 ssyl.c -o ssyl
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

typedef struct map_s {
   struct map_s * next;
} map_t;

struct data {
  map_t * map;
};

jmp_buf * exceptionp ;

void insert ( map_t * * const mapl ) {
  map_t * new = malloc(sizeof(map_t));
  if ( new == NULL )
    longjmp ( * exceptionp , 1 ) ;
  new->next = * mapl ;
  fprintf (stderr,"\ninsert:%p", (void*)new);
  * mapl = new ;
}

int main() {
  jmp_buf jbmain ;
  exceptionp = & jbmain ;
  if ( setjmp ( * exceptionp ) ) {
    fputs("OutOfMemory\n",stderr);
    exit(1); }
 struct data d;
 d.map = NULL;
 fprintf (stderr,"\n0.main:%p", (void*)d.map);
 insert(&d.map);
 fprintf (stderr,"\n1.main:%p", (void*)d.map);
 return 0;
}
```

Чтобы переменную `d.map` можно было поменять с помощью другой функции нужно передать указатель на эту переменную, так-как аргументы во все функции передаются копированием. Переменная аргумент `map_t * * const mapl` имеет значение только внутри функции `insert`. Она указывает на удалённый указатель типа `map_t *`. Взять и поменять значение удалённого указателя можно с помощью записи `* mapl`.

Comment: Jmp тут только отвлекает, но спасибо за ответ